# Facebook Graph IP filtering

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, scrapy

I've read few posts around about the limitations on 600 requests in 600 seconds that Facebook Graph Api sets on requests.

This question is about getting some clarification in the issue I'm facing.
I'm doing requests, quite simple to the FB Graph:

So, from my home I run:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/?id=https://www.example.com/article/the-name-of-the-article/
```

(Having the trail slash is not trivial)
which gives me empty results:

```
{
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 605
   },
   "og_object": {
      "id": "XXXXX6ZZ70301002",
      "description": "text",
      "title": "title",
      "type": "article",
      "updated_time": "2019-03-09T00:15:06+0000"
   },
   "id": "https://www.example.com/article/the-name-of-the-article"
}
```

I took the url from js code in the website.
Instead, running the Scrapy crawler, on the same url, still from home network, gives me the same as above:

```
{
   "share": {
      "comment_count": 0,
      "share_count": 605
   },
   "og_object": {
      "id": "XXXXX6ZZ70301002",
      "description": "text",
      "title": "title",
      "type": "article",
      "updated_time": "2019-03-09T00:15:06+0000"
   },
   "id": "https://www.example.com/article/the-name-of-the-article"
}
```

Which is more than fine for now and the js-code-scraping system seems to be working. The results contain all the information from js calls to FB Graph.

Hands on server side, the crawler runs as expected, but having a closer look at the results, information coming from js code execution is not there.
I've checked the whole code, in other url which also fires js actions to provide html content and the code actually works fine.

Then, repeating the simple:

```
curl https://graph.facebook.com/v2.0/?id=https://www.example.com/article/the-name-of-the-article
```

this time from the server ip, it replies:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#4) Application request limit reached",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "is_transient": true,
    "code": 4,
    "fbtrace_id": "ErXXXXZZrOn"
  }
}
```

Regarding ip-blocks, the code wasn't able of delivering more than 600 requests. Actually it sent less than 10 requests to the graph api.

Obviously, the information coming from js requests to the Fb Graph Api from server side is missing.

I tried from different servers, from different providers, to check if there was a Ip filter on Cloud providers, but it seems that is not the case, as in every server the results are the same.

What is going on here?
Why the js requests do not get valid response data when they are fired from server ip addresses? (as it gives the error OAuthException:Application request limit reached also using the curl command)

Thanks for any clue

Comment: Looks like you are making these requests without any access token (surprised that even still works; must be an exception for this endpoint I guess), so the API has no way of associating this with any particular app id in the first place. So likely you get rate-limited way earlier.

Comment: Hi @04FS, thanks for that. Then it could mean that the page authenticates itself with facebook, and the scraping keeps this auth (in cookies for example), the weird is that, this authentication fails when the scraping is done in the server.
Do you think it is needed further authentication (other than the one that works from my home pc) from the server ip? or maybe a problem with the HTTP origin...

Comment: Supply an access token with your request. (The basis for that is of course having an app id first, so if you don’t have one yet, go create one first of all.)

Comment: Thanks. I shall do it. But still, I use this code with no access token, and the code works fine in my home(local) environment, but not remotely, and it is not an issue of the js scraping...

Comment: It might be that user cookies are taken into account when you make this request directly in the browser, but that is not really how the API is supposed to be used in the first place. There is an officially documented exception for the need to supply an access token for the user profile picture redirect endpoint, it might be that this one is still “open” in this regard to, because it only delivers public data about Open Graph objects. But in regard to rate limiting, you should supply an access token in any case, otherwise you might always get “cut off” at any point.